# Persistent 87 error when calling AddUser

Tags: c++, c, winapi, user-management

I'am trying to add local user with NetAddUser, but constanly getting this error code - 87, with no reason. Piece of code is done, as far as I can see, accordingly to MSDN. What could be wrong here?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <Lm.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "netapi32.lib")

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    wchar_t wchLogin[256] = { 0 };
    wchar_t wchPassword[256] = { 0 };
    DWORD dwError = 0;
    USER_INFO_1 user_info;
    //ZeroMemory(&user_info, sizeof(USER_INFO_1));
    NET_API_STATUS err;

    wcscpy_s(wchLogin, L"test_user");
    wcscpy_s(wchPassword, L"123");


    user_info.usri1_name = wchLogin;
    user_info.usri1_password = wchPassword;
    user_info.usri1_priv = USER_PRIV_ADMIN;
    //user_info.usri1_script_path = L"";

    //user_info.usri1_flags = UF_SCRIPT;
    //user_info.usri1_home_dir = NULL;
    //user_info.usri1_comment = NULL;
    //user_info.usri1_flags = UF_SCRIPT | UF_WORKSTATION_TRUST_ACCOUNT;


    err = NetUserAdd(NULL, 1, (LPBYTE)&user_info, &dwError);
    if ( err != NERR_Success )
    {
        printf("Error adding user: %d\n", err);
    }


    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Have you looked up what that error code means?

Comment: @AlanStokes, yes that's parameter error. In the end it has nothing to do with parameters, I read MSDN carefully and found what was wrong. Thanks for paying attention.

Comment: You're allowed to answer your own question, if you've figured out the problem.

Comment: You should be zeroing out that `USER_INFO_1` struct.  Otherwise those fields you're not filling in will have uninitialized data, and the API function will use those bogus values, causing errors to occur.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "it has nothing to do with parameters".  You were providing a parameter whose value wasn't valid, so you got an invalid parameter error.  That's fairly straightforward! :-)

Comment: @HarryJohnston, yea and nay.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was in MSDN, here's the excerption:

> **usri1_priv**
>
> Type: DWORD
>
> The level of privilege assigned to the usri1_name member. **When you call the NetUserAdd function, this member must be USER_PRIV_USER**. When
>   you call the NetUserSetInfo function, this member must be the value
>   returned by the NetUserGetInfo function or the NetUserEnum function.
>   This member can be one of the following values. For more information
>   about user and group account rights, see Privileges.